# Junit. How to test the method that call the other class constructor in a method

Tags: java, junit

Please help me in testing the following scenario

```
public class Myproject {
 Teacher tescher;
 public Teacher test(teacher teach){
     String name="A";
     String sub="b";
     tescher= new Teacher(name,sub);
     return tescher;

 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This class is not readable. "teacher" is a type? How can you assign instance to type?

Comment: Its not clear what this does. Why does it take an argument `teach`? why does it set a field? why is the Teacher called `tescher`? I assume the method should have a return type?

Comment: Edit your question, don't put the code in comment. And use the "Code Sample" button this time instead of the "Blockquote" one :)

Comment: I have edited it please4 check

Comment: I think you still need to expand your question a bit to make it clearer. Is `public Teacher test(teacher teach)` the method you'd like to test? At the moment `test(teacher teach)` is not syntactically correct and the parameter is never used anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
public void test(){
Myproject myProject = new Myproject();
Teacher teacher = myProject.test(new Teacher("some","thing")); // Assuming Teacher don'thave default constuctor
assertEquals("A",teacher.getName()); //assuming static import 
assertEquals("b",teacher.getSub());

}
```

I suggest you should have following in your code:

```
tescher= new Teacher(teacher.getName(),teacher.getName());
```

instead of

```
 tescher= new Teacher(name,sub);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would just call the method and check that

1. a Teacher instance with the correct properties set is returned.
2. the field is set to that Teacher instance. Possibly by using some other method in the class which uses that field.

In more complex cases where you can't afford to the other object actually getting created, or where you can't easily verify that it has the correct properties [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) might be usefull.